# javscript side Shows null value ,but server side shows values Howto resolve it?

Tags: apex, lightning

```
<aura:component controller="ActionController"  implements="force:hasRecordId,force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global">
<aura:attribute name="theId" type="String"/>
<aura:attribute name="options" type="String[]"/>
<aura:attribute name="wrplst" type="WrapperCriteria[]"/>
<aura:attribute name="option" type="List" />
<aura:attribute name="selectedValue" type="String"/>
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
<p>
    <b>Creating Action Criteria </b>
</p>
<h3 class="slds-section-title--divider">
    <I> Action Criteria</I>
</h3>
<table >
    <tr class="slds-text-title--caps">
        <th class="head">
            <I>Action</I>
        </th>
        <th class="head">
            <I>Object Name</I>
        </th>
        <th class="head">
            <I>Component</I>
        </th>
        <th class="head">
            <I>Operator</I>
        </th>
        <th class="head">
            <I>Special Operator</I>
        </th>
        <th class="head">
            <I>Special Operator * Value</I>
        </th>
        <th class="head">
            <I>Special Operator / Value</I>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.wrplst}" var="a">
        <tr>
            <td class="cell" >
                <p>
                    <button type="button" onclick="{!c.RemoveClick}">remove</button>
                </p>
            </td>
            <td class="cell" >
                <p>
                    <lightning:select name="mySelect" label=" " aura:id="mySelect" value="{!v.selectedValue}" onchange="{!c.doSomething}" >
                        <aura:iteration items="{!v.option}" var="item">
                            <option label="{!item.label}" value="{!item.value}" selected="{!item.selected}"/>
                        </aura:iteration>
                    </lightning:select>
                </p>
            </td>
            <td class="cell" >
                <P>
                    <ui:inputText value="{!a.ObjectApiNAme}"/>
                    <!-- check conditions -->
                </P>
            </td>
            <td class="cell" >
                <p>
                    <lightning:select name="selectItem" label=" ">
                        <option value="None">None</option>
                        <option value="+ Addition">+ Addition</option>
                        <option value="- Subtract  ">- Subtract</option>
                        <option value="* Multiply ">* Multiply</option>
                        <option value="/ Divide">/ Divide</option>
                    </lightning:select>
                </p>
            </td>
            <td class="cell" >
                <p>
                    <lightning:select name="selectItem" label=" " >
                        <option value="None">None</option>
                        <option value="*">*</option>
                        <option value="*/">*/</option>
                        <option value="/">/</option>
                    </lightning:select>
                </p>
            </td>
            <td class="cell" >
                <p>
                    <ui:inputText value="{!a.specialOperatorValue}"/>
                </p>
            </td>
            <td class="cell" >
                <p>
                    <ui:inputText value="{!a.specialOperatorSlashValue}"/>
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </aura:iteration>
</table>
<lightning:button variant="brand" label="Add row" onclick="{!c.AddRow }" />
```

**Lightning controller**

```
({

doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
    alert('do Init is calling ::::');
    helper.pageLoad(component);
    helper.compVal(component); //here Ive to call getcompoent
},
doSomething: function(component, event, helper) {
    alert('iam change func');
    var xval = component.get("v.selectedValue");
    alert('xval  :::' + xval);
    var wraper = component.get("v.wrplst");
    var wrapval = JSON.stringify(wraper);
    alert(':::wrapval:::::' + wrapval);

},
RemoveClick: function(component, event, helper) {},
AddRow: function(component, event, helper) {

 }
});
```

**Helper**

```
   ({
pageLoad: function(component, event, helper) {
    var Idx = component.get("v.theId");
    alert('Idx value ::::' + Idx);
    var action = component.get("c.pageLoading");
    action.setParams({
        "id": Idx
    });
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === 'SUCCESS') {
            alert(':::::::' + JSON.stringify(response.getReturnValue()));
            component.set("v.wrplst", response.getReturnValue());
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},
compVal: function(component, event, helper) {
    var opts = [{
            value: "",
            label: "--None--"
        },
        {
            value: "Pay_Element_Master__c",
            label: "Pay Element"
        },
        {
            value: "CTC_Master__c",
            label: "CTC Master"
        }
    ];
    component.set("v.option", opts);

   }
 })
```

**Apex Controller**

```
public class ActionController {
     @AuraEnabled
     public static List < WrapperCriteria > pageLoading(string id) {
      Map < String, String > ctcMasAPINames = new Map < String, String > ();
        List < Action_Criteria__c > RecordsToBeInserted = new List < Action_Criteria__c > ();
        List < Action_Criteria__c > RecordsInserted = new List < Action_Criteria__c > ();
        List < WrapperCriteria > warpList = new List < WrapperCriteria > ();
        Criteria_Master__c cmas = new Criteria_Master__c();
        List < Criteria_Master__c > updatedCrimasters = new List < Criteria_Master__c > ();

        list < SelectOption > ObjNames = new List < SelectOption > ();
        ObjNames.add(new SelectOption('', '--None--'));
        ObjNames.add(new selectoption('Pay_Element_Master__c', 'Pay Element'));
        ObjNames.add(new selectoption('CTC_Master__c', 'CTC Master'));
        cmas = [select id, Name, Action_Criteria__c from Criteria_Master__c where Id = : id];

        RecordsInserted = [select id, Action_Criteria_API_Name__c, Action_Criteria_Field_Name__c, Criteria_Master__c, Object_API_Name__c, Operator__c, Object_Name__c, Special_Operator__c, Special_operator_slash_value__c, Special_operator_value__c from Action_Criteria__c where Criteria_Master__c = : id order by Sequence_No__c];

        for (Action_Criteria__c ac: RecordsInserted) {
        WrapperCriteria wrp = new WrapperCriteria(RecordsInserted.size());
        wrp.record = ac;
        wrp.ObjectApiNAme = ac.Object_API_Name__c;
        wrp.FieldName = ac.Action_Criteria_API_Name__c;
        wrp.index = warpList.size();
        wrp.CriteriaMasId = ac.Criteria_Master__c;
        wrp.Operator = ac.Operator__c;
        wrp.SpecialOperator = ac.Special_Operator__c;
        wrp.specialOperatorSlashValue = ac.Special_operator_slash_value__c;
        wrp.specialOperatorValue = ac.Special_operator_value__c;
        warpList.add(wrp);
        }
        system.debug('**********wrapList values****************' +   warpList);

        return warpList;
        }
 }
```

**Wraper class**

```
    public class WrapperCriteria {
    @AuraEnabled
    public Integer index {
    get;
    set;
   }
@AuraEnabled
public Action_Criteria__c record {
get;
set;
}
@AuraEnabled
public string CriteriaMasId {
get;
set;
}
@AuraEnabled
public String ObjectApiNAme {
get;
set;
}
@AuraEnabled
public Criteria_Master__c CriteriaMas {
get;
set;
}
@AuraEnabled
public String SpecialOperator {
get;
set;
}
@AuraEnabled
public String SelObjectName {
get;
set;
}
@AuraEnabled
public String FieldName {
get;
set;
}
@AuraEnabled
public String Operator {
get;
set;
}
@AuraEnabled
public decimal specialOperatorSlashValue {
get;
set;
}
@AuraEnabled
public decimal specialOperatorValue {
get;
set;
}
@AuraEnabled
public List < SelectOption > ComponentsInWpr {
get;
set;
}

public WrapperCriteria(Integer count) {

 }
}
```

**Problem**:  In server side I am getting wrapper list values,and java script side It shows wrapper list value is null.I have attached image for more Information[image] [image]

I have edited add one more [debug Log] image:  [image]

Comment: from the alert it doesn't look like null - it is an array. also - can you share the server side debug log?

Comment: Ya.exactly .I have  already attached server side debug log  [please check the  image ]

Comment: It looks fine, for pinpointing the problem try narrowing down the return value - try to return a string and see if your client gets it, then slowly change the return value to see where the problem is

Comment: I have done that..clients side I'am getting the value..But If I use wrapperList it shows null value in client side..Pleased help me to resolve that problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the returned list as a JSON string and then parse it back in lightning controller. something like this:

In your apex class:

```
public static String pageLoading(string id) {
...
return JSON.serialize(warpList);
}
```

Now in your setCallback in lightning controller:

```
action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === 'SUCCESS') {
            component.set("v.wrplst", JSON.parse(response.getReturnValue()));
        }
    });
```

I have faced this issue in the past and this is how I approached. Not sure though why this happens. I am open for more discussion on this.